# Too many apache processes in D state

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, performance

Please see the following screenshot. There are too many apache processes all in D(disk sleep) state with very high ram usage.

[image]

Is there a way to know what's causing these processes to stay in D state and eating so much memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first look at `apachtctl fullstatus` (you may need to install w3m first, a text-based web-browser).

You are out of memory (look at your swap figures), so you need to down-tune the number of processes that are started in your apacheconf. Look at `MaxClients`, `ServerLimit`, `MaxSpareClients`, `MinSpareClients`, etc.